# How to create class library for custom controls

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, custom-controls

I need to create a class library with .net standard. In the library, I need to create a custom entry and image.

I have added the ContentView page in which I created one entry and image. but if I go for custom entry(borderline option included in entry) how can I do in class library for three platforms?

Does anyone knows how to create a library with two or three custom controls

Any help is really appreciated[image]

Comment: The easiest way is to inherit the Control Class.  In may be easier to use a Panel and put new object in the Panel and make the Panel the new control.

Comment: You will need some custom renderers

Comment: Did you check this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view